# trying to join 2 tables on zip code where both tables contain first 5 matching zips but other table includes 10 digit zips

Tags: sql-server-2014, zipcode

Here is what I have.  The zip codes in the Customer table may have 5 or 10 digit
zip codes where the zip codes in the Counties table contains all of the 5 digit zip codes. I thought the left(c.[Post Code], 5) would truncate the 'on' in the join but doesn't.

```
 select     c.[No_], 
            c.[Name], 
            c.[Address],  
            c.[City], 
            left(c.[Post Code], 5), 
            kc.[County]
            from [Customer]c
            left join [Counties]kc on c.[Post Code] = kc.[Post Code]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to say this, but you aren't joining on the zip codes.  If you were, you could use

where left(c.[Post Code], 5) = kc.whatever-the-post-code-value-is.

In this case, you are going to return the customer information at least once and potentially as many times as there are counties for a city.  But the postal code will always be the customer.post code.

Comment: Then you need to do the left() on the where clause.  "where left(c.[Post Code], 5) = kc.[Post Code]

Comment: Why that was almost too easy.  Thanks.